# ESlint linting gulpfile.js

Tags: javascript, gulp, ecmascript-6, eslint, arrow-functions

Hi i use Atom and plugin called lint-eslint for linting my javascript code and it does work fine but i have one really annoying linting error on my gulpfile.js

Here is the code that triggers linting error, i'm using airbnb .eslintrc configuration file for ESlinter.

```
gulp.task('lint', () => {
 return gulp.src(['**/*.js', '!node_modules/**', '!src/**'])
 .pipe(gulpif(args.verbose, gprint()))
 .pipe(eslint())
 .pipe(eslint.format())
 .pipe(eslint.failAfterError());
});
```

Note that i'm trying to use arrow syntax.
I'm getting following error *Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body.*
 And when i remove the `return` it goes away.

It has to do with the early return stream from gulp src is there some other way to return it or how do i correct the error i know i can ignore the file but i want to know if there is another way to return `gulp.src()`

Comment: *"when i remove the `return` it goes away."* Because `() => {foo}` is different from `() => foo`. The first returns `undefined`, the latter returns the value of `foo`. Hence they might not be able to simply remove the braces like you can with `() => { return foo; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES6 arrow function can return an object without word 'return' like this:

```
let func = () => ({key: 'value'});
let a = func();   // and a will be an object {key: 'value'}
```

This is ES6 standard.

And eslint-airbnb style guide believes that if your arrow function does nothing but return an object, the 'return' will not be necessary. So your code could go like this:

```
gulp.task('lint', () => (
 gulp.src(['**/*.js', '!node_modules/**', '!src/**'])
  .pipe(gulpif(args.verbose, gprint()))
  .pipe(eslint())
  .pipe(eslint.format())
  .pipe(eslint.failAfterError())
));
```

See more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions about Returning object literals.

Comment: note that the `;` after the last pipe call should be removed otherwise it's a syntax error

Comment: Thanks for explanation i will read the specifications in more detail.

Comment: Don't really see how the first part of your answer (about the object) is relevant here.

Answer (score 2):

Since your function simply return a value, you can omit the curly braces `{}` and the `return` statement, which makes the code lighter and easier to read.

The rule involved is [arrow-body-style](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-body-style) which *"enforces the consistent use of braces in arrow functions"*.

```
gulp.task('lint', () => 
  gulp.src(['**/*.js', '!node_modules/**', '!src/**'])
   .pipe(gulpif(args.verbose, gprint()))
   .pipe(eslint())
   .pipe(eslint.format())
   .pipe(eslint.failAfterError())
);
```

Comment: Thanks, i guess that happens when you don't read arrow syntax specification really thoroughly.